# c++ template argument deduction from another argument

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction, pimpl-idiom

I'm using [pimpl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) pattern in my code, so for each class `X`, there will be a corresponding impl class `XImpl`

Say we have `A`, `AImpl`, `B`, `BImpl`, `C`, `CImpl`, where `A`,`B`,`C` are similar class, and I would like to write some template function for them.

```
template <typename T, typename TImpl>
std::shared_ptr<const T> GetObjectById(int id);
```

This function is to query Object by its id(type could be `A` or `B` or `C`). In the function definition, I do need to use both `T` and `TImpl`.

Users will use this function in this way:

```
auto a = GetObjectById<A, AImpl>(1);
auto b = GetObjectById<B, BImpl>(2);
auto c = GetObjectById<C, CImpl>(3);
```

And as you can see, for each type `T`, `TImpl` is always bind to it. So I want to simplify its usage to

```
auto a = GetObjectById<A>(1);
auto b = GetObjectById<B>(2);
auto c = GetObjectById<C>(3);
```

More importantly, this can hide `AImpl` from user side.

Is there anyway to bind second argument to the first argument? i.e., the second argument doesn't participate in argument deduction, it's specified by some mapping relationship I defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something as follows ?

```
template <typename T, typename TImpl = typename T::impl>
std::shared_ptr<const T> GetObjectById(int id);
```